# Laravel 4.2 created_at column gives "The format separator does not match" error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, models

I am trying to access the ***created_at*** column in one of my models and I get the following error:

> The format separator does not match. The format separator does not match. The format separator does not match.

The error actually repeats 3 times.

This is how I try to access the column:

```
$model->created_at
```

I do not have $timestamps set to false in my model and I can access the other columns just fine.
What is the problem?

Comment: Do you have `getDateFormat` defined in your model? If yes, show the code

Comment: Are you by any chance using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes I am using MySQL. And I did have getDateFormat() defined.

Comment: Not sure about MySQL, but I've seen this issue with SQL Server detailed here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1756

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you override the ***getDateFormat()*** in your model?
I ran into this problem last week. The problem is the datetime format. I have a link that explains the error.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4181

If you have overridden the getDateFormat(), comment out the function and see if it works.

If not, make sure the datetime format in your database is not funky.

Comment: If you had overridden the getDateFormat(), it also would have messed up the ***updated_at' field of the model. Check to make sure that both created_at and updated_at throw the same error.

Comment: Both columns were giving the same error. I commented out the function and got it to work (after hours of messing with it in the last day or so).