# Accessing Laravel relationship as array throws 'The format separator does not match'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5

This error only happens if I try to use `toArray()` on the returned collection.

Code in my controller:

```
public function find_order(){
$input = Input::all();

$orderNumber = $input['OrderNumber'];
$orderType = $input['OrderType'];

$details = Order::where('orderNumber', '=', $orderNumber)->first();
$status = $details->orderStatus()->get();

dd($status->toArray());

return view('orders.view_details', compact('details', 'status'));
}
```

If I use `dd($status);` on line 7 I get a collection with the correct data.

[image: image of dd($status) results]

When I use `dd($status->toArray);` I get the `The format separator does not match` error.

EDIT: When I use the following code, I get the desired string, `Box`.

```
$status = $details->orderStatus()->first();
dd($status['orderStatus']);
```

But I'm wondering, is there is a better way for me to access this data?

Comment: The problem is likely the non-standard datetime format you're using.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846440/laravel-4-2-created-at-column-gives-the-format-separator-does-not-match-error

Comment: I'm not sure that's it. `toArray()` will work on my `$details` object, and both tables have the same datetime field type.

Comment: Judging by your seconds to 3 decimal places, I'm guessing you're using SQL Server datetime column which has incessant conflicts with PHP's DateTime microsecond format (6 decimal places). More details in this issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1756